# Column name error while inserting into SQlite database

Tags: sqlite

```
def insertorupdate(ID,naam):
count=0
conn=sqlite3.connect("Faceset.db")
cmd="SELECT Id from students"
cursor=conn.execute(cmd)
for row in cursor:
    count=1
if(count==1):
    print("1")
    cmd="UPDATE students SET Name="+str(naam)+" WHERE Id="+str(ID)
else:
    print("2")
    cmd="INSERT INTO students(Id,Name) Values("+str(ID)+","+str(naam)+")"
conn.execute(cmd)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
ID=input('enter user ID')
naam=str(input("enter your name"))
insertorupdate(ID,naam)
```

The following error pops up whenever I try to run this program.(The input is 1 and Ahaan). The database has two columns Id and Name.

```
enter user ID1
enter your nameAhaan
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "capture.py", line 26, in <module>
insertorupdate(ID,naam)
File "capture.py", line 21, in insertorupdate
conn.execute(cmd)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Ahaan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose the name inside single quotes:

```
cmd = "UPDATE students SET Name = '" + str(naam) + "' WHERE Id = " + str(ID)
```

So now this results to:

```
UPDATE students SET Name = 'Ahaan' WHERE Id = 1
```

Your code produced this:

```
UPDATE students SET Name = Ahaan WHERE Id = 1
```

so `Ahaan` was taken as a column name.

Read more [here](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q24)

Comment: Well that did solve the problem. Thank you :) @forpas